# How does react-scripts install extra dependencies?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npm-install, react-scripts

To reproduce what I'm talking about

1. Create an empty directory
2. cd into the directory and run npm init
3. run `npm install react-scripts`
4. look at the node_modules directory. `react-scripts` exists inside node_modules, but it also installs many other dependencies required to run a project with create-react-app.

Looking at react-scripts directory in node_modules, I don't see any pre or post install scripts. I do see a react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js script that im assuming is the entrypoint for the code installing these extra dependencies.

How is that file being run?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` not only installs the package itself, in this case `react-scripts`, but also the package's direct (and indirect) dependencies. Dependencies are listed in the `package.json` file in the package's root directory.

Comment: react-scripts dependencies can be viewed here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/package.json